# Android Searchable Dropdown spinner?

Tags: android, spinner, autocompletetextview

I have some data (list of countries) with 249 entries. I want to force the user to choose one of these options.

Usually I would use a spinner, however I feel like 249 entries would be too many to scroll through, particularly for people with smaller phones.

Is there anyway in android to have either:
a) a dropdown spinner that is searchable (so the panel where the chosen selection is usually displayed can be used to enter a search term)
b) an `AutoCompleteTextView` that forces the user to select one of the options from the AutoComplete suggestions.

Thanks.

Comment: autocompletetextview can help you in this situation

Answer (score -1):

Beginning in Android 3.0, using the SearchView widget as an item in the action bar is the preferred way to provide search in your app.

http://developer.android.com/training/search/setup.html